# dd no such file or directory

Tags: backup, dd

I've booted up arch live cd, with the idea of creating a disk image. There are 2 hdds (/dev/sda - i want this image, and /dev/sdb - the image will be copied here, but as a backup file (not rewrite), so i can use it later)

[image: fdisk output]

So I mounted the /dev/sdb1 as:

```
mount -t auto /dev/sdb1 /mnt/hdd
```

And then i tried

```
ddrescue if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/hdd/backup.dd
```

But it failed saying cant open input file, no such file or directory.

What am I doint wrong?

Comment: `sda1` rather than just `sda`?

Comment: @Kusalananda that would just create an image of the first partition, which is usually not what you want when you're trying to make an image of the whole disk.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Horkyze please post a screen shot of the `ddrescue` command you entered along with the output. Without that we can't be sure that there isn't a typo somewhere in your command. Please also post a screenshot of the results of `ls -l /dev/sd*`.

Comment: On the screenshot, where it says `I/O error, device fd0` -- **fd0** usually signifies the first *floppy* disk.  Perhaps there's some other reason not given for imaging the first *hard* disk `/dev/sda`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to its man page, ddrescue should be called like this:

```
SYNOPSIS
       ddrescue [options] infile outfile [logfile]
```

So, in your specific case, `ddrescue /dev/sda /mnt/hdd/backup.hdd`; no `if=` or `of=`.

Comment: i feel embarrassed now why did i assume that the synopsis is same as dd... thanks